# Error: Unknown user permission: ManageCssUsers

Tags: deployment, ant, migration-tool

I could not deploy permissionset that contain MangeUserCss permission, via ant migration tool. In permission set metadata file it looks like code below:

```
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
    <name>ManageCssUsers</name>
</userPermissions>
```

What is it for? Should I enable some feature on target org before deployment

Comment: may be this permission is related to `Environment Hub`

Comment: @TusharSharma This is not Environment Hub.  My org has that, but not Env. Hub.

Comment: I don't know what it is for, but I think only production orgs have it.

Comment: Remove the User permissions in the permission set and then try deploying.

Comment: @sushma that is what I've done 4 months ago. My question is more about what is this permission for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That permission corresponds to the "Edit Self-Service Users" checkbox on the profile. In my case, enabling communities for my org added that permission option.

References:

- https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=editing_user_information.htm&language=en
- https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_enable.htm&language=en_US